# Create data adapter with web application feature in SharePoint 2013 to access custom field type data in Microsoft Office products

Tags: 2013, custom-field-types

I have created **a custom field type** by inheriting `SPFieldLookup`class to extend the capability of standard lookup columns. It is working as expected in SharePoint lists and libraries.

In SharePoint document libraries, you can open a word document in Microsoft word desktop application, where you can edit the document and also add values in metadata columns from it. Here, all SharePoint's standard columns are supported **but the custom field type we make by inheriting standard columns are not supported by default.**

Please refer the attached screenshot here:
[image]

The properties highlighted with red border are columns with custom field types.

These are the custom field types advanced from standard lookup columns. I would like to support these type of columns in **Microsoft Word, Access, and Excel**, so user can add/edit values for this column from Microsoft Word desktop application.

I have searched for the same on Google but get only that it seems possible with creation of **data adapter with web application feature and Timerjob**. But I can't find any steps to create them.

Any high level steps or a sample for the same would be very helpful to me.

There are various 3rd party products available in market which connects these custom field types with Microsoft word, Access and Excel desktop applications such as:

1. Boost cascaded lookup: http://www.boostsolutions.com/cascaded-lookup-tutorial.html#navfourth
2. Artfulbits-Column Data Adapter: https://www.sharepoint-artfulbits.com/Products/column-data-adapter#description